# How to convert JSON property value to array of keys and values

Tags: c#, json, regex

I am using Newtonsoft.JSON to serialize a DataTable into a single JSON payload.

The resulting payload looks like:

```
[
    {
        "Name" : "Example_Name_1",
        "Value": "Example Value 1"
    },
    {
        "Name" : "Example_Name_2",
        "Value": "Example Value 2"
    },...
]
```

For use with an external library, I need it to like:

```
[
    {
        "Name" : "Example_Name_1",
        "Value": {
            "Value": "Example Value 1"
        }
    },
    {
        "Name" : "Example_Name_2",
        "Value": {
            "Value": "Example Value 2"
        }
    },...
]
```

Is the any way to make this transformation?
I've been looking at Regular Expressions, but haven't had any luck.

I've been playing with different regex patterns and I saw another SO solution that was similar, but used JavaScript Mappings?

```
var strJson = "[{\"Name\": \"Example_Name_1\",\"Value\": \"Example Value 1\"}]";

var pattern = "{\"Name\": \"*\",\"Value\": \"*\"}";
var replacement = "{\"Name\": \"*\",\"Value\": {\"Value\": \"*\"}}";
var input = strJSON;
var result = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, replacement);

return result;
```

[EDIT]
The DataTable has just 2 columns:  Property_Name, & Property_Value
I'm serializing it with

```
    JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myDataTable);
```

Comment: Please provide serialization code too

Comment: @ingvar

'JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myDataTable);'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the Newtonsoft.Json.Linq namespace. It contains classes like JObject, JArray, and JToken to achieve what you're trying to do.

Here's a short snippet to start you along:

```cs
var strJson = "[{\"Name\": \"Example_Name_1\",\"Value\": \"Example Value 1\"}]";
var newObject = JArray.Parse(strJson);
for(int i = 0; i < newObject.Count; i++)
{
    newObject[i]["Value"] = new JObject()
    {
        { "Value", newObject[i]["Value"] }
    };
}
```

You can iterate through the Descendants of the original JObject looking for the key "Value", or something else, to convert it from a string to a JObject, like my code sample.

Comment: System.ArgumentException: 'Can not add Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue to Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.'

Comment: @Rhystic, I updated the answer so it works correctly. This time I tested the code :)

Comment: to get a minified Json string, I added:
        return newObject.ToString(Formatting.None);

Answer (score 3):

I would probably use LINQ to transform the datatable to your preferred format. You didn't provide the actual datatable, but the transformation would be something like this:

```
IEnumerable<Data> yourData = GetData();

var transformedData = yourData.Select(d => new {
    Name = d.Name,
    Value = new {
        Value = d.Value
    }
});

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(transformedData);
```

The `json` variable should now (hopefully) be in the format you want without needing to use regex.

Answer (score 2):

You can just parse the response into json and loop through the data to create a new object.
Please check out the code which i created using your sample data.

```js
var runCode = function(){
  var strJson = "[{\"Name\": \"Example_Name_1\",\"Value\": \"Example Value 1\"},{\"Name\": \"Example_Name_2\",\"Value\": \"Example Value 2\"}]";
  parsedJson = JSON.parse(strJson)
  new_json = []
  for (var i = 0; i < parsedJson.length; i++) {
    temp_json = {}
    temp_json['Name'] = parsedJson[i]['Name']
    temp_json['Value'] = {
      'Value': parsedJson[i]['Value']
    }
    new_json.push(temp_json)
  }
  console.log(new_json)
}

runCode()
```

Comment: The snipped looks like it works great.  Would you mind converting it to a C# function please?

Comment: @Rhystic sorry for that but i do not have a good knowledge of c#.
But you can use this logic to loop through the json.
All you need to do is loop through the json and store the value in a temp dictionary and then append it to a list